# How do i control magento2 proxy setting?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.3, proxy

I'm a Magento 2 beginner and not well English.

I have installed and used **Magento 2** for a test in **non-connecting internet PC**.

Now, my Magento 2 need to connect to the **proxy server** when **checkout** is finished.

Because I can't finish checkout and reason of this problem is **non-proxy**.

How do I control magento2 proxy setting?